# Redshift - Sum output from two different queries into a single query

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to sum output of 2 different sql in Redshift.

SQL1:

```
select count (*) from table1; -- Output : 10
```

SQL2:

```
select count (*) from table2; -- Output : 14
```

I am trying to build a query that would show the total of both these queries. `Expected output : 24`

Answer (score 1):

Figured the solution:

```
select ((select count(*) from table1) +
       (select count(*) from table2)) as count
```